# install ubuntu12.04 on dell r710 raid 5

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, dell, raid

I have created a virtual disk 0 with raid 5 on Dell r710.  This virtual disk 0 consists of 6 physical disks.  Each disk comes with 1TB disk space. I used the bootable CD that I created to try to install uBuntu 12.04 server.  During the installation process, I only saw the virtual disk 0 was available for partition. Shall I partition the physical disks and configure the software array during the installation of uBuntu 12.04 or shall I configure the RAID 5 in Dell r710 and then partition the virtual disk 0 during the installation of uBuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of HARDWARE RAID, the physical disks are abstracted away behind the virtual disk you created so all the OS has to care about is one disk. It has no idea it's a RAID volume, it's not necessary.